# Git workflow for multiple branches merged prior to merging to master

Tags: git

I'm trying to simplify our current workflow. We have a multiple developer, multiple branch environment where:

1) each branch starts off master
2) prior to release each branch that is ready for release, is merged manually (not Pull Request) to a branch called RELEASE
3) After that is fully tested we put it into production.
4) If it survives without rollback we then merge it back to master.

We are getting more people and it's hard to manage. What I'd like is for each developer to do a pull request to branch RELEASE (not master). Then I can merge them myself, and test the entire package, put it into production and merge it to master once it's proven itself. Sometimes merges get messy and I don't want a bunch of git resets and failed rebases on the master branch.

Is there any problem with this?

Comment: As your team grows you may want change your testing to be more along the lines of [Integration Testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292128(v=vs.71).aspx). Specifically as mix of bottom up and top down testing. It may be worth it to have pull requests based on features and not specific developers.

Comment: You might consider the widely-used and supported (plugins for git CLI and native support in many GUI clients) [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow.